# An elementary inequality involved harmonic series

Tags: calculus, inequality

Is it true that for every  $i\in \mathbb N $:

$$\frac { 1 } { i^2} +\sum _{j \in \mathbb N} \frac{1}{i^2 + j^2}> \frac { 1 } { i} ?$$

I guess it is true, can anyone help me with proof?

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\sum_{j\in\mathbb Z}\frac1{i^2+j^2} ~=~ \frac1{i^2}+2~\sum_{j\in\mathbb N^\star}\frac{1}{i^2+j^2} ~=~ \frac\pi i~\coth(i\pi).~$ This can be proven by differentiating the natural logarithm of [Euler's infinite product formula for the sine function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\frac{1}{i^2+j^2}\geq \frac{1}{(i+j)(i+j-1)}=\frac{1}{i+j-1}-\frac{1}{i+j}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the monotonicity of the integral. Since $$\frac{1}{i^2 + j^2} >\int_{j}^{j+1} \frac{1}{i^2 + x^2} \, dx$$ it follows that
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2 + j^2} > \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{i^2 + x^2} \, dx.$$ The last integral is easy to evaluate - you get $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{i^2 + x^2} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{2 i} > \frac 1i.$$

Answer (score 0):

We have, on comparison to the Riemann sum for

$f(x)=\frac{1}{i^2+x^{2}}$,

$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{i^{2}+j^{2}}>\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{dx}{i^{2}+x^{2}}=\frac{1}{i}\left ( \frac{\pi}{2} \right )>\frac{1}{i}.$